# How to use more than one WHERE clauses in JPA, HIBERNATE?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to get data with two 'WHERE CLAUSES'. But data i found just first on row table the looping according to count of data. How i can get all data of this case?

```
This is with spring boot, jpa hibernate, using @NamedQuery

@Entity
@Table(name = "m_account")
@NamedQueries(  
        {  
            @NamedQuery(name="findByAccountSegment4IDNullAndAccountFlagAndAccountCompanyId", query = "FROM MAccount e "
                    + "WHERE e.accountSegment4ID IS NULL AND e.accountFlag = ?1 AND e.accountCompanyId = ?2"),
            @NamedQuery(name="findByAccountCompanyIdAndAccountFlag", query = "FROM MAccount e WHERE e.accountCompanyId = ?1 AND e.accountFlag = ?2 "),
            @NamedQuery(name="findByAccountCompanyId", query = "FROM MAccount e WHERE e.accountCompanyId = ?1")
        }
        )
public class MAccount {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_companyid")
    private String accountCompanyId;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Account Id can not be empty")
    private String accountId;

    @Column(name = "account_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Account Name can not be empty")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name = "account_segment4id")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Account Segment 4 id can not be empty")
    private String accountSegment4ID;

    @Column(name = "account_segment4consolid")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Account Segment 4 consolidasi can not be empty")
    private String accountSegment4Consolidasi;

    @Column(name = "account_normalaccount")
    @NotEmpty(message = "AccountNormal can not be empty")
    private String accountNormal;

    @Column(name = "account_activeyn")
    @NotEmpty(message = "AccountFlag can not be empty")
    private String accountFlag;

    @Column(name = "account_userid")
    @NotNull(message = "Account Users can not be empty")
    private int accountUserId;

    @Column(name = "account_lastupdate")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Account last update can not be empty")
    private String accountLastUpdate;
```

the result is just first row. like this :

```
{
    "status": "00",
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "accountCompanyId": "6000",
            "accountId": "51101011001",
            "accountName": "Kas Pusat",
            "accountSegment4ID": "5110101",
            "accountSegment4Consolidasi": "5110101",
            "accountNormal": "D",
            "accountFlag": "N",
            "accountUserId": 1,
            "accountLastUpdate": "2019-07-11 23:04:10"
        },
        {
            "accountCompanyId": "6000",
            "accountId": "51101011001",
            "accountName": "Kas Pusat",
            "accountSegment4ID": "5110101",
            "accountSegment4Consolidasi": "5110101",
            "accountNormal": "D",
            "accountFlag": "N",
            "accountUserId": 1,
            "accountLastUpdate": "2019-07-11 23:04:10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *more than 1 where clause.*?

Comment: @NamedQuery(name="findByAccountCompanyIdAndAccountFlag", query = "FROM MAccount e WHERE e.accountCompanyId = ?1 AND e.accountFlag = ?2 "),

Comment: I want filter data with 2 condition, companyId and Flag. But the problem is this query just get data on first row @AlanHay